# Selenium | Java | Can anyone suggest how to select this element?

Tags: java, selenium, selector, element

Need help to select an element that has the following attributes

```
<a href="" tabindex="-1" ng-bind-html="match.label uibTypeaheadHighlight:query" class="ng-binding ng-scope"><strong>Lantus</strong> 100 iu (Insulin)</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify element using either className,linktext,css selectors or xpath. Below are the examples, you can try any of these below.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//descendant::strong[contains(text(), 'Lantus')]"));

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ng-binding.ng-scope");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//strong[contains(text(), 'Lantus')]"));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ng-binding ng-scope']"));

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Lantus 100 iu (Insulin)");

driver.findElement(By.className("ng-binding"));
```

Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: the first option worked.. Thanks. Could you also explain, how?

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these below code.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Lantus 100 iu (Insulin)"));
```

**Explanation:-** Using `linkText` locator click on `Lantus 100 iu (Insulin)` link.

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ng-binding ng-scope']"));
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `class` attribute of `<a>` tag.

> OR

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ng-binding.ng-scope"));

OR

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='ng-binding ng-scope']"));
```

**Explanation of cssSelector :-** Use `class` attribute of `<a>` tag.

Comment: Have you try this code? Does my explanation of code `helped` you?

Comment: If it does helped you, then please mark this answer as `Accepted`

Answer (score 0):

`WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='ng-binding ng-scope']"));
// do whatever you need with the link`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below line of code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement hyperLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Lantus')]"));
```